# Mongodb 3.6.3 disappears after 2 weeks on centos 7 ec2 instance

Tags: mongodb, aws, amazon-ec2, wiredtiger, centos-7

My Mongodb has disappeared 2 times, after 2 weeks, over the weekend within a 4 week time period.

I had a snapshot to recover from but I can't keep on recovering my db every 2 weeks. In an ec2 instance where I hosted Mongo and the API in the same place, this is not an issue.

Side note - does anyone know if it is possible to completely disable db.dropDatabase() or db.collection.drop()?

Below is my mongod.conf file

```
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data
  logpath: /log/mongod.log
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
   wiredTiger:
    prefixCompression: true
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

Any ideas for how this happens or anyone who has ever solved a similar problem would be greatly appreciated.

`var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

```
2018-02-26T17:14:09.799+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=# port=port dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=ip-*
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: amazon
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-26T17:14:09.987+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid", timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-02-26T17:14:09.988+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1382M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-02-26T17:14:10.692+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-26T17:14:10.693+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 038fb561-1163-46cb-bcae-b68ddebb4081
2018-02-26T17:14:10.700+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.6
2018-02-26T17:14:10.703+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: c994079b-4e9b-416f-91b4-4cbc60e2c118
2018-02-26T17:14:10.710+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2018-02-26T17:14:10.710+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-02-26T17:14:21.788+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54282 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-26T17:14:21.788+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:54282 conn: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.3" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) ", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64" } }
2018-02-26T17:14:23.882+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:54282 (0 connections now open)
2018-02-26T17:19:10.711+0000 I STORAGE  [thread2] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: b181a7ff-d0e5-456e-bee5-ff7e40f32d0a
2018-02-26T17:19:10.739+0000 I INDEX    [thread2] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2018-02-26T17:19:10.739+0000 I INDEX    [thread2]        building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2018-02-26T17:19:10.740+0000 I INDEX    [thread2] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2018-02-26T17:28:02.551+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54292 #2 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-26T17:28:02.551+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:54292 conn: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.3" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) ", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64" } }
2018-02-26T17:33:15.093+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:54292 (0 connections now open)
2018-02-26T17:34:20.689+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2018-02-26T17:34:20.689+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-02-26T17:34:20.689+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-02-26T17:34:20.690+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-02-26T17:34:20.692+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-02-26T17:34:20.763+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-02-26T17:34:20.763+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2018-02-26T17:34:20.763+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

journalctl return these red lines

`Failed to create mount unit file /run/systemd/generator/data.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?`
also for `log.mount` and `journal.mount`

`piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr`
`Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...`

Comment: Is whole mongodb (program and databases) disappearing or just databases? After disappear, do still /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log exists? If yes, what that file and /var/log/syslog (or messages) tell about that incident?

Comment: I added the log as it currently appears, might be incorrect since I did have to restore the data from a backup snapshot

Comment: As per the log warning `Access control is not enabled for the database`, this deployment currently allows unrestricted access to anyone who is able to connect. It also has `bindIP` set for all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`), so if this instance has a public IP and no firewall you have opened up your deployment to the internet. That would be one likely reason for data randomly disappearing. I would review tutorials in the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) and make sure you have enabled access control, network encryption, and a firewall.

Comment: I second with @Stennie, probably someone (person or script) contacted your mongodb instance and gave command to drop your database(s).

Comment: I have another weird question. After starting the backup, I was only able to run the database with `sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all  --fork --logpath /log/mongod.log` because even though `sudo service mongod start` said okay, it would fail right after.

It currently fails if I just overwrite the functioning start command. Is this because the command has to be cancel first or could there be a deeper issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your latter problem (start with sudo) is because some of the files or directories are NOT owned by user mongod.

When you state `sudo service mongod start` mongod process is started with user `mongod:mongod` and now you have situation that some (or all) of the files/directories:

- /data  (storage.dbPath at config)
- /log/mongod.log (systemLog.path at config)
- /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid (processManagement.pidFilePath at config)

are **not** owned by user `mongod`

So, do multiple `sudo chown -R mongod: XXXX` (where XXX is right path/file) will **fix** this problem and your `sudo service mongod restart` command will work again.

Comment: I tried the above on all 3 routes and after doing it to the pid route I received this error when trying to run `sudo service mongod restart`. `sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 997, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set` I am really scared because this post says I destroyed my whole system https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Comment: That error says that /etc/sudo.conf should be owned by root user, not anybody else! So, `chown root: /etc/sudo.conf` will fix that error. Anyway, why you changed owner of /etc/sudo.conf, it has nothing to do with our current mongod ownership problem.

Comment: I never `sudo chown -R etc/sudo.conf`, I only used the /data /log /.ipd routes as specified above. It appears that it ruined the pid as well and I could no longer ssh in afterwards.

I had an ec2 snapshot and recovered from that afterwards, so in the end I didn't lose anything.

Comment: It looks like that somehow your chown command got "loose" and changed whole /etc/ -directory (and all sub-directories of it).